# How do I add a string value to DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

```
string = 'cool'
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['string_values'])
```

Append

```
df.append(string)
```

I get this error when I try to append it into df. (Is it only for numerical data?)

```
cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'str'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

I just want to add a string value `string = 'cool'` into the dataframe, but I get this error.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think best is use `DataFrame` contructor and assign one element list:

```
string = 'cool'
df = pd.DataFrame([string], columns=['string_values'])
print (df)
  string_values
0          cool
```

If strings are generated in loop best is append them to one list and then pass to constructor only once:

```
L  = []
for x in range(3):
    L.append(string)

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['string_values'])
print (df)
  string_values
0          cool
1          cool
2          cool
```

**Performance**:

```
In [43]: %%timeit
    ...: L  = []
    ...: for x in range(1000):
    ...:     value1 = "dog" + str(x)
    ...:     L.append(value1)
    ...: 
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['string_values'])
    ...: 
1.29 ms ± 56.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [44]: %%timeit
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['string_values'])
    ...: for x in range(1000):
    ...:     value1 = "dog" + str(x)
    ...:     df = df.append({'string_values': value1}, ignore_index=True)
    ...: 
1.19 s ± 34.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Gotcha, and if I want to add another value under string value `cool`, I would just have to call `df = pd.DataFrame([new_value])` again?

Comment: @Chipmunkafy - I think it is possible, but really slow. Better is create list, fill it by values by append and last pass to DataFrame.

Comment: @Chipmunkafy - Check performance why `append` to Dataframe is really bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to add more than a single value, see [@jezraels answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53236864/5535114).
If you only need to add **a single value**, you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['string_values'])
value1 = "dog"
df = df.append({'string_values': value1}, ignore_index=True)

#   string_values
# 0           dog

value2 = "cat"
df = df.append({'string_values': value2}, ignore_index=True)

#   string_values
# 0           dog
# 1           cat
```

Check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html).

Comment: Your solution is really not recommended, because slow.

Comment: Yeah, but it's what OP wants. If he needs performance, he is definitely better off passing in a list as your answer explains, but he is asking how to add a single value. He may be confused and want to add more than a single value though.