# How to assign bs4 strings to pandas dataframe in for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML string that I am successfully able to use beautifulsoup4 on to extract the elements I need.

the HTML strings are in a list and I am wanting to extract only certain elements out of the strings and assign them to dataframe columns.

Current code:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

lst = [ <html>,<html>]

df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in lst:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(i)
    
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        df['links'] = str(link.get('href'))
        #print(link.get('href'))
        
    #get all text messages
    soup.find_all('p')
    df['messages'] = str(soup.find_all('p'))
    
    #get author name
    soup.find_all(class_="author--name")
    df['author'] = str(soup.find_all(class_="author--name"))
    
    #get username
    soup.find_all(class_= "author--username")
    df['username'] = str(soup.find_all(class_= "author--username"))
```

All the soup lines of code are producing the data I need, but why is the dataframe not assigning the string values to the dataframe columns?

I can see that from an empty dataframe, the code creates the new columns but there are no values.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the problem lies in how you are using the database itself. Replace the soup with dummy text.

Comment: @Someone I set `df['links'] = 'a'` and still no luck.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add an example of of of the `lst` elements?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53236855/how-do-i-add-a-string-value-to-dataframe You may need to pass a list instead of string. Does soup.find_all('p') return a list? If not, can you create a list of those values instead of using str()?

Comment: @JonathanLeon @Jack  i enclosed all assignments in brackets and it worked. Like so:`[str(link.get('href'))]`

Comment: thx for letting us know what worked.

Comment: @JonathanLeon ofcourse! thats the point of stack right?!. I will update answer below with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to wrap the assignments in brackets like so:

```
for i in lst:
    
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(i)
    #print(soup)

    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        df['links'] = [str(link.get('href'))]
        #print(link.get('href'))
        
    #get all text messages
    soup.find_all('p')
    df['messages'] = [str(soup.find_all('p'))]
    
    #get author name
    soup.find_all(class_="author--name")
    df['author'] = [str(soup.find_all(class_="author--name"))]
    
    #get username
    soup.find_all(class_= "author--username")
    df['username'] = [str(soup.find_all(class_= "author--username"))] text messages
    soup.find_all('p')
    df['messages'] = str(soup.find_all('p'))
    
    #get author name
    soup.find_all(class_="author--name")
    df['author'] = str(soup.find_all(class_="author--name"))
    
    #get username
    soup.find_all(class_= "author--username")
    df['username'] = str(soup.find_all(class_= "author--username"))
```